# Second button on home page is not starting the new activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to the coding world so please don't be too harsh on me here.  I have an app I am designing and am going to have multiple activity buttons on the home screen but when I programmed the second button it will not go to the third activity.  The first button works just fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated I am teaching myself to code as I find it interesting and enjoyable but am still learning.
Also, all activities are called out in the manifest.

**This is main activity java**

```
    '''
     import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button Button ;
        Button Button3 ;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
            setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
    
            Button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            Button.setOnClickListener( v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
    
                Button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
                Button3.setOnClickListener( v1 -> {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity( intent1 );
'''
```

**This is the third activity java**

```
'''
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_third );

        button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener( v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
'''
```

**This is main xml file**

```
    '''
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="122.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="349dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="122.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="430dp"
        android:text="@string/watch_dog"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="361dp"
        android:text="@string/protecting_your_loved_ones"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="192dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="555dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="199dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="232dp"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="192dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="623dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="199dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
        android:text="@string/maps"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
'''
```

**This is the third activity xml file**

```
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/third_activity"
    tools:context=".ThirdActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="127dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:text="@string/back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
'''
```

Comment: Your button click for Button3 is inside the click listener for Button

Answer (score 0):

According to your code block at here..

```
       Button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button.setOnClickListener( v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            Button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
            Button3.setOnClickListener( v1 -> {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity( intent1 );
```

Your button3 will be initialized after you click on the "Button" object.
Pulling it out of your Button.setOnClickListener block and placing it below will do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked great

Answer (score 0):

just pull the code outside...

```
            Button.setOnClickListener( v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
});
    
                Button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
                Button3.setOnClickListener( v1 -> {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity( intent1 );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked great

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check the scope of the first button

What you did wrong is you call your second button inside of the first button on click

just remove your second button click listener from the scope of the first one

will solve your problem easily